# Remove header from telerik grid (RAZOR)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, telerik

I have a telerik grid showing 2 levels of details, and for the first level, I want to completely remove the header.

I tried using styles.. i.e.:

```
                     column.Bound(x => x.Name)
                         .ClientTemplate("<#= Name#>")
                         .HeaderHtmlAttributes( new { style="display:none;"})
```

But I still get a "gray header thing" over the expand pluse, and it still shows an anoying white layer...

[image]
How to completely remove it?

Comment: can you post more of your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind that, I found a solution although would have prefered to do it via razor than do it through  a jquery/javascript hack, but with Telerik, you got to expect that!

Seems a telerik grid's header is wrapped in a  ***`thead`*** element with a ***`t-grid-header`*** css class.

The styles you apply to a column with ***`column.Bound(...).HeaderHtmlAttributes`*** are only applied to the ***`th`*** element of the ***`thead`***.

I just added this at the end of my .cshtml file and the header was gone.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".t-grid-header").css('display', 'none');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<MasterTableView ShowHeader="false">
    <Columns>
    //etc
    </Columns>
</MasterTableView>
```